Category with underline
I have a notation confusion about category and functor in Lecture Notes in Mathematics 2247, p38, as follows
$$\operatorname{res}^G_{G_0}:\underline{G\textit{-CW}} \rightarrow \underline{G_0\textit{-CW}} .$$Unfortunately, I can’t find any book shows how to define the notation of category with underline. I search on StackExchange, and find that such notation seems to be in connection with some concepts like enriched category and underlying category.

Underline is too nondescript, it can mean absolutely anything. You need to find the relevant parts of the textbook that defines the notation. Maybe they just put underlines under all categories.

Eee, I've looked at the lecture notes, and I don't think it means anything. A typo?

Different authors use different notations. As far as I can tell from the notes you're citing, $\underline{(-)}$ is simply the notation used for (ordinary) categories.
It's not something that I would personally use, as underlining can have various meanings in related fields, for example, enriched category theory or parametrized higher category theory is plagued with underlines.
